# Type '[T]' (array Type) does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, generics, swift3

**Let me explain the issue with example.**

I have two protocols named - Mappable(available on Git) and Responsable(I created that which conforms to the Mappable protocol)

```
protocol Responsable: Mappable {
  static func getResponse(map: Map) -> Self
}
```

**Approach 1**
then I have struct 'NSIResponse' which is generic and conforms to Mappable and generic T is Resposable type

```
struct NSIResponse<T>: Mappable where T: Responsable {
mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
    response = T.getResponse(map: map)
  }
}
```

After that I created the struct of User Object which conforms to the Responsable protocol.

```
struct User: Responsable {

  var id: Int ?
  mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
      id <- map["id"]
    }
  static func getResponse(map: Map) -> User {
    guard let response = Mapper <User>().map(JSONObject: map["response"].currentValue)
    else {
      return User()
    }
    return response
  }
}
```

**Approach 2**
Well, I created getResponse or Responsable because I don't want to use more lines in mapping method in NSIResponse like following

```
 mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
   switch T.self {
    case is  User.Type: response = Mapper<User>().map(JSONObject: map["response"].currentValue) as? T
    case is Array<User>.Type: response = Mapper<User>().mapArray(JSONObject: map["response"].currentValue) as? T
    default: response <- map["response"]
    }
  }
```

I dont want to use previous approach because if I do then I have to write every single two lines of code for every class. Result, function length will increase. Therefore, I created the T.getResponse(map: map) method.

**Now Issue which I am facing**

```
let jsonResponse = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject]
let nsiResponse = NSIResponse<User>(JSON: jsonResponse) // WORKING
let nsiResponse1 = NSIResponse<[User]>(JSON: jsonResponse) // NOT WORKING and getting Type '[User]' does not conform to protocol Responsable
```

However, its working fine in case of Approach 2.. 
I would be very appreciated if you could help me with Approach 1.

I hope you understood my question.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this error is because the type `Array` does not conform to `Responsable`, only `User` does. In approach 2, you cover that case so it works.

What you have to do is extend the `Array` type, so it can conform to `Responsable`:

```
extension Array: Responsable {
    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
      // Logic
    }

    static func getResponse(map: Map) -> User {
      // Logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, First of all, Thanks for your reply. Technically you right but It wont work in my case I want something to do with Generic T so that  T can take Array of object as well.

Comment: @PraviJay You can specify the type the array contains like this: `extension Array where Element == User`. This makes it so that the elements must be of type `User`. Does that do what you want?

Comment: I tried extension Array where Element == User... Still getting same error in NSIResponse<[User]> line.

Comment: However,  I got the Idea through your answer. Let me try something related to your given answer. I will let you know if it will work or not.

Comment: Could you please suggest me any other alternative of Approach 2. let me elaborate more.. 

struct NSIResponse<T>: Mappable {

mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
    response = T.getResponse(map: map)
  }
}

mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        switch T.self {
        case is  User.Type: response = Mapper<User>().map(JSONObject: map["response"].currentValue) as? T
        case is Array<User>.Type: response = Mapper<User>().mapArray(JSONObject: map["response"].currentValue) as? T
        }
    }

Comment: @PraviJay not really. If I could get enough code so that I can run it locally I could play around with it and I might be able to come up with something.

Comment: @PraviJay Just had a thought. Could you do `extension Array where Element == Responsable {}`, then run the functions on the elements of the array? If that doesn't work, I can't think of anything.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess conditional conformances was added in Swift4.0... I haven't downloaded Swift4.0 yet, but if you're using Swift4, i guess you can use something like this: `extension Array: Responsable where Element: Responsable {}`